# Spring-data-mongodb not persist multiple objects on list

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am using Spring-data-mongodb and i can persist an object on a list, but when i try to add another, it doesn't work, the application doesn't throw an exception.

this is my Json:

```
[
  {
    idUser: "4a9f10d9-e19f-42af-ba00-891a567cc41f",
    login: "peter",
    password: "mypassword",
    email: "peter@eeee.com",
    patients: 
      [
        {
          idPatient: "d31e8052-36d3-4285-9f97-454f3437812d",
          name: "ada",
          birthday: 1363474800000,
          idUser: "4a9f10d9-e19f-42af-ba00-891a567cc41f",
          region: 
          {
            idRegion: "d8acfa45-486e-49e0-b4e6-edde6743cf30",
            name: "Madrid"
          },
          personalCalendars: null
        },
        null
      ]
   }
]
```

As you can see, my first Patient element is correctly, and the second was insert as null.

I leave my code:

User.java

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String id;

@Indexed
private UUID idUser;

@Indexed(unique = true)
private String login;

private String password;

@Indexed(unique = true)
private String email;

@DBRef
private List<Patient> patients;

@PersistenceConstructor
public User(UUID idUser, String login, String password, String email, List<Patient> patients){
    this.idUser = idUser;
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
this.patients = patients;
}
```

Patient.java

```
@Document(collection = "patients")
public class Patient implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String id;

@Indexed
private UUID idPatient;

private String name;

private Date birthday;

private UUID idUser;

private Region region;

@Transient
private List<PersonalCalendar> personalCalendars;

@PersistenceConstructor
public Patient(UUID idPatient, String name, Date birthday,UUID idUser, Region region){
    this.idPatient = idPatient;
    this.name = name;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.idUser = idUser;
    this.region = region;
}
```

and the DAO whereI do the insert.

```
@Override
public Patient createPatient(User user, Patient patient) {
    this.mongoOps.save(patient , "patients");
    this.mongoOps.save(user , "users");
    return this.getPatientById(patient.getIdPatient());
}
```

The console returns this, but no persists the patient:

```
15:16:16.718 [tomcat-http--6] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Saving DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, idPatient, name, birthday, idUser, region]
15:16:16.723 [tomcat-http--6] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils - Getting Mongo Database name=[application]
15:16:16.747 [tomcat-http--6] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Inserting 1 documents into namespace application.patients on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:119}] to server 127.0.0.1:27017
15:16:16.761 [tomcat-http--6] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert - Insert completed
```

I need help.
Thanks a lot

Comment: And what is an exception?

Comment: no exception, I will update with console answer

Comment: I only can add a object in the collection and I don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you use Spring Data with MongoDB, use it properly:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

}
```

Now just inject UserRepository via `@Autowired` annotation:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

User user = new User();
Patient patient = new Patient();
user.addPatient(patient);

// Just call save from userRepository to save your User with Patient.
// save method will return instance of saved user (together with instance of
// patient)
User user = userRepository.save(user);
```

Note that `save` method can also be used for updating of existing `User`. If `User` is new (not having generated id) it will be inserted. If user exists (has generated id) it will be just updated.

Presuming that `User` class has a `addPatient` method that looks like this:

```
public void addPatient(Patient patient) {
    this.patients.add(patient);
}
```

Also, make sure that your list is initialized: `List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: It was my mistake, i was using a Indexed(unique) and I didn't drop the collection when I did my changes. The mongodb wasn't work for it for this reason.

However thanks for the repository suggestion, I updated my project.

Comment: @JavierOliver You are welcome. Always give yourself some time. ;)